# Setting unknown property: yii\authclient\AuthAction::successCallBack

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

When I try login using social media in Yii2 if google, facebook, twitter and GitHub error. I'm sure is true for my configuration on \basic_yii2\config\web.php. This my configuration :

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'authClientCollection' => [
         'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
         'clients' => [
             'google' => [
                 'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Google',
                 'clientId' => 'example',
                 'clientSecret' => 'example',
              ],
             'facebook' => [
                 'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
                 'clientId' => 'example',
                 'clientSecret' => 'example',
             ],
             'twitter' => [
                 'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Twitter',
                 'consumerKey' => 'example',
                 'consumerSecret' => 'example',
             ],
             'github' => [
                 'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Github',
                 'clientId' => 'example',
                 'clientSecret' => 'example',
             ],
           ],
        ],
```

and this my configuration for \basic_yii2\controllers\siteConttroler.php :

```
public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
            'auth' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
                'successCallBack' => [$this, 'successCallBack'],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function successCallBack($client)
    {
        // get user data from client
        $userAttributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
        print_r($userAttributes);
        exit;
    }
```

and this description error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property name is [`successCallback`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-authclient-authaction.html#$successCallback-detail) not `successCallBack`:

```
'auth' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
    'successCallback' => [$this, 'successCallBack'],
],
```